# Unsubscribe Firebase Push Notifications from unknown devices

Tags: firebase, push-notification, unsubscribe

I have implemented the Firebase push notifications in my web application.
I then subscribed from multiple unknown/random devices to receive these push notifications.

**How do I unsubscribe unknown devices for my push notifications?**

Answer (score 0):

**The ability to unsubscribe the user from firebase is still missing.** 
Refer [this firebase document](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/#unsubscribe_the_user) for more details

To do this you will need to call unsubscribe() on a PushSubscription (from the subscribed client)

*I am assuming that is not possible in your case.* Thus, I would advise you to

> change your `Web Push certificates` from the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/).